# A weird problem in <<Go Programming Language>>

Tags: go, synchronization, channel

**Description:**
Here is code in Chapter 9-7 of ***Go Programming Language***.

You have to call **func New()** to init a container before you call any other funcs.

It's weird that the author created a blocking channel in **func New()** to send requests.

I think this will make the program work in a *serial* way.

For Example:  if there are more than one goroutine calling **func Get()** at the same time, will the requests be handled in a serial way in the loop of **server** goroutine?

Could anyone please give me a explanation? Thank you!

```
/**
 * create a memo and run the monitor goroutine of it.
 * here is a question:
 * since the request channel is blocking, does it mean that func Get is serial?
 */
func New(f Func) *Memo {
    memo := &Memo{requests: make(chan request)}
    go memo.server(f)
    return memo
}

/**
 * make a new request to query the data.
 */
func (memo *Memo) Get(key string) (interface{}, error) {
    response := make(chan result)
    memo.requests <- request{key, response}
    res := <-response
    return res.value, res.err
}

/**
 * start the monitor goroutine.
 * Notice that the cache is running here.
 */
func (memo *Memo) server(f Func) {
    cache := make(map[string]*entry)

    // handle each of the requests
    for req := range memo.requests {
        e := cache[req.key]
        if e == nil {
            e = &entry{ready: make(chan struct{})}
            cache[req.key] = e
            go e.call(f, req.key)
        }
        go e.deliver(req.response)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `New` function starts the `server` in a goroutine, and `server` reads requests from the `requests` channel. Since `requests` is unbuffered, only one goroutine can write to it at any time. However, note the implementation of the server: it reads a request, and starts a new goroutine to handle that request, immediately going back to listening from it. So, request processing gorotines are created one by one, but each goroutine runs concurrently.

When you call `Get`, it waits for the `server` method to handle the request, but as soon as the request handler goroutine is created, it can serve other `Get` requests. Each `Get` call will wait for a response to arrive on a different channel, written by another goroutine.

So in short: no, `Get` can be called from many goroutines, and each call will create a separate goroutine to handle that request.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer really helps!